# Using ipywidget for multiple choice test

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm pretty new to python and python notebooks.  Im trying to create a Jupyter notebook that will display an image from a list of images and give the user 4 choices to what that image in the from of clickable ipywidget buttons. Once the user clicks their choice, I want to replace the image with a new image and repopulate the buttons with 4 new choices.

I know how to clear the image output and close the button widgets using button.close(), but I can't seem to figure out how to redraw the buttons with new choices. Once I've closed the container, I cant figure out how to loop back to the top since I'm stuck in the on_button_clicked function once a choice is made.   Here's what I have so far, though I know its no where near working yet and it probably way off in the approach.  Note I don't need to use ipywidgets, but it seemed like a good choice in the sense of clickable buttons:

```
x = ['tree.jpg','house.jpg','car.jpg','door.jpg','train.jpg','moon.jpg']

choices = random.sample(x, 4)
correct = random.choice(choices)

display(Image(correct))
time.sleep(3)

button1 = widgets.Button(description = x[0])
button2 = widgets.Button(description = x[1])
button3 = widgets.Button(description = x[2])
button4 = widgets.Button(description = x[3])

container = widgets.HBox(children=[button1,button2,button3,button4])
display(container)


button1.on_click(on_button1_clicked)
button2.on_click(on_button2_clicked)
button3.on_click(on_button3_clicked)
button4.on_click(on_button4_clicked)


def on_button1_clicked(b):
     # [insert code to record choice] 
    container.close()
    clear_output()

def on_button2_clicked(b):
     # [insert code to record choice] 
    container.close()
    clear_output()

def on_button3_clicked(b):
     # [insert code to record choice] 
    container.close()
    clear_output()

def on_button4_clicked(b):
     # [insert code to record choice] 
    container.close()
    clear_output()
```

thanks alot!

Comment: You should include your import statements also! Have you considered using a `while` loop which `break`s after a condition is met?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i understand what you want to do, you can put everything into a separate function and have that called everytime a button is clicked:

```
import random
import time
from IPython.display import Image, display, clear_output
from ipywidgets import widgets

x = ['tree.jpg','house.jpg','car.jpg','door.jpg','train.jpg','moon.jpg']

def redraw():
    choices = random.sample(x, 4)
    correct = random.choice(choices)

    display(Image(correct))
    time.sleep(3)

    button1 = widgets.Button(description = choices[0])
    button2 = widgets.Button(description = choices[1])
    button3 = widgets.Button(description = choices[2])
    button4 = widgets.Button(description = choices[3])

    container = widgets.HBox(children=[button1,button2,button3,button4])
    display(container)

    def on_button1_clicked(b):
        # [insert code to record choice] 
        container.close()
        clear_output()
        redraw()

    def on_button2_clicked(b):
        # [insert code to record choice] 
        container.close()
        clear_output()
        redraw()

    def on_button3_clicked(b):
        # [insert code to record choice] 
        container.close()
        clear_output()
        redraw()

    def on_button4_clicked(b):
        # [insert code to record choice] 
        container.close()
        clear_output()
        redraw()

    button1.on_click(on_button1_clicked)
    button2.on_click(on_button2_clicked)
    button3.on_click(on_button3_clicked)
    button4.on_click(on_button4_clicked)

redraw() # initializes the first choice
```

Some comments:

- I suppose that in the description for the buttons you want the
  text from the sample of 4 you have chosen (i.e. from `choices`) not
  the first four elements of list `x` (since those don't change).
- You may not want to hardcode the number of choices to 4 because then you hardcode 4 buttons and 4 button functions etc. You may want to generate a list of buttons based on the number of choices you want. Something like:

  ```
  nchoices = 4
  x = ['tree.jpg','house.jpg','car.jpg','door.jpg','train.jpg','moon.jpg']

  def redraw():    
      choices = random.sample(x, nchoices)
      correct = random.choice(choices)

      display(Image(correct))
      time.sleep(3)

      buttons = [widgets.Button(description = choice) for choice in choices]

      container = widgets.HBox(children=buttons)
      display(container)

      def on_button_clicked(b):
          # [insert code to record choice]
          container.close()
          clear_output()
          redraw()

      for button in buttons:
          button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

  redraw()
  ```

  saves about half of the code.
- I don't know exactly what you want to do with the choice by clicking a button but i can imagine you want to compare the `choice` to `correct` and subsequently do something with that information. You can do the comparison simply by `b.description == correct` and as a suggestion what to do then is to color the buttons `'green'` if the condition is `True` and `'red'` otherwise like so:

  ```
  def on_button_clicked(b):
      choice = b.description
      b.color = 'white'
      b.background_color = 'green' if choice == correct else 'red'
      time.sleep(5)
      container.close()
      clear_output()
      redraw()
  ```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  thank you so much!  I didn't know that a function inside a function like on_button_clicked(b) could call the parent function redraw().  That is VERY useful to understand.

Comment: @Snapula - You are welcome! It is a type of [recursion](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/recursion.html) which works in this case. Very useful indeed :)